# Listbox - add two identical items - WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, listbox, wpf-controls

I have a ListBox (WPF) and I am adding to it strings at runtime....
If I try to add string that is already exists in the ListBox it throws me an exception..... telling that this item is already in the ListBox....
How can I add the same strings to ListBox ?
Because I have situations in my application when I do have to add 2 identical strings....
thanks....

The ListBox -

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox_MyListBox" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Background="Transparent" MaxHeight="170" BorderThickness="0" Margin="3">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Margin="3" Padding="2" Text="{Binding}" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="13"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

in the code behind I add the string like that -

```
 this.listBox_MyListBox.Items.Add(text.ToString());
```

Comment: I know of no limitation like this, so I'm not sure that the ListBox is  your problem here. Can you post a little more code that would show us exactly where the exception occurs?

Comment: instead of this why don't use a list or observable collection bound to the listbox and you can add what ever data to the collection

Comment: @KishoreKumar my point is that it IS possible to add two identical items to a ListBox

Comment: Just tried, it works fine for me...

Comment: @paul You right paul , I didn't pay attention to some line in my code that is throwing the exception (the listbox is fine).....thanks!

Comment: It was a bug in previous versions of Visual Studio. It has been fixed in VS 2010. try dat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add duplicate items to listbox, it allows without any issue
Example:

```
private void Window_Loaded ( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
   listBox_MyListBox.Items.Add ( "demo" );
   listBox_MyListBox.Items.Add ( "demo" );            
}
```

Note:
It would not let you add duplicate if you are using any of data sources which dont allow duplicate:
Dictionary or Hashtable may not allow duplicate entries, if that is the case with you then choose List or datatable as datasource

Answer (score 1):

why not a simple list?

the easy not mvvm way:

```
 public List<string> MyItems {get; set;}

 listBox_MyListBox.ItemsSource = MyItems;

 MyItems.Add("t1");
 MyItems.Add("t2");
 MyItems.Add("t1");//again
```

i would use a viewmodel with your list and bindging to the listbox. but the code above will work too.